# Stuck on how to Pass data to Functions

Tags: c#, function

I would like to ask for some help/guidance once more.

This time I am trying to pass information from one function to another in order for it to be completed.

I'll post an example here:
additional code above this but is irrelevant to topic and you can assume it is correct.

```
CalorieIngestion()
{
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        sName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What day is it 1-8?");
        sDay = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        if (sDay == "1")
        {
            CalorieCount();
        }
}
CalorieCount()
{ int iCal1;
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ingested");
iCal1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sName + ".txt", true))
{
sw.WriteLine("Calories consumed on " + sDay + "" + iCal1);
}
```

Okay I imagine I need to pass the sName variable and the sDay variable over to CalorieCount() but I am not quite sure how to... my gut tells me to write in the () next to CalorieCount "psName" and "psDay".

Comment: Have you read a C# tutorial yet? Also, please post code that compiles.

Comment: Actually what am I saying, of course I will go search for a c# tutorial, I will delete this now, I realised how futile it is to ask for help when it is such a basic task.

Comment: This question isn't *terrible* but it is very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass parameters, you first need to define your function in such a way to accept them. Functions look like:

> < access modifier > < return type > FunctionName ( < ListOfParameter > ) { < FunctionBody > }

And a parameter is:

> < Type > VariableName

So in your case:

```
private void CalorieCount(string day, string name) { }
```

The parameters are accessed from the function body as if they were local variables. And to call it, you have to provide values for each parameter:

```
if (sDay == "1")
{
   CalorieCount(sDay, sName);
}
```

As an aside, you don't normally use the "c","s", etc. style variable names in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to fix it

```
     CalorieIngestion()
        {

        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
                sName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("What day is it 1-8?");
                sDay = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                if (sDay == "1")
                {
                    CalorieCount(sName, sDay);
                }

        }
      static void CalorieCount(string psName, string psDay)
        { int iCal1;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount ingested");
        iCal1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(psName + ".txt", true))
        {
        sw.WriteLine("Calories consumed on " + psDay + "" + iCal1);
        }
return;
```

I hope this serves as help to anyone else struggling with passing parameters. Thank you to
@BradleyDotNET

EDIT: 
It is also important to make sure when you pass parameters that you pass them in the same order, I passed sName first and then sDay but called them as sDay and sName and it really screwed up the StreamWriter!

Comment: What is the class name? Is it `CalorieIngestion`? If that's the case, then you should add the class. Also, in general, don't put anything in a constructor that takes a substantial amount of time. Like console I/O.

Comment: Also, note that most professional programmers don't prefix variables like you are doing. After a while it's obvious that it's a parameter ("p") and that it's a string ("s").

Comment: John, I'm only doing what I've been told to do, I am not a professional programmer, I am a greenhorn, I've been told by my university to prefixes to create familiarity. After I finish my first year we can assume I will be using the correct syntax.

Comment: @John Saunders No sorry, I do not wish to disclose that information.